# Scikitlearn Regression with Support Vector Machine score/r^2 for a specific point python

Tags: python, methods, scikit-learn, regression

I'm doing a regression with the support vector machine from sklearn and I need to calculate the deviation from the real value for each point. I only found the method "score" to calculate the overall performance of the modell. Is there another method, which will give me the error for each data point? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can do something like: `residuals = y_test - clf.predict(X_test)`

Comment: @Mahdi thanky ou very much:)